# Cannot get sliding menu button to work correctly? (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to make the button on the top left of the action bar work, I can get the slide to work but clicking on the button calls the same method but it keeps on calling only the else part of the method.

Here is the method for sliding out the drawer:

```
-(void)drawerAnimation {
    NSLog(@"drawer animation called");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:-5];

    CGFloat new_x = 0;
    if (menuDrawer.frame.origin.x < self.view.frame.origin.x ) {
        NSLog(@"drawer animation called menu origin if");
        new_x = menuDrawer.frame.origin.x + menuDrawerWidth;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"drawer animation called menu origin else");
        new_x = menuDrawer.frame.origin.x - menuDrawerWidth;
    }
    menuDrawer.frame = CGRectMake(new_x, menuDrawer.frame.origin.y, menuDrawer.frame.size.width, menuDrawer.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Here is the way I add the button but I do have a triangle yellow warning sign saying

```
incompatible pointer to integer conversion UIBarButtonItemStyle
```

Here is the button in another .m file, with the drawer animation being in the parent navigation controller:

```
//add navigation top left bar items
    UIBarButtonItem *menuBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"] style:self target:self action:@selector(drawerAnimation)];

    //add items to array
    NSArray *actionButtonItems = @[shareItem, cameraItem];
    NSArray *leftActionButtonItems = @[menuBtn];

    //add array to navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = actionButtonItems;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = leftActionButtonItems;
```

The rest of the sliding menu controller code:

```
@interface SlidingMenuViewController ()

@end


@implementation SlidingMenuViewController
@synthesize menuDrawerWidth, menuDrawerX, recognizer_open, recognizer_close, mainTitle, menuItems;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    int statusBarHeight = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height;
    menuDrawerWidth = self.view.frame.size.width * 0.75;
    menuDrawerX = self.view.frame.origin.x - menuDrawerWidth;
    menuDrawer = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(menuDrawerX, self.view.frame.origin.y+statusBarHeight, menuDrawerWidth, self.view.frame.size.height-statusBarHeight)];
    menuDrawer.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];


    //initialize open and close
    recognizer_close = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];

    recognizer_open = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipes:)];

    //for opening and closing drawer
    recognizer_close.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    recognizer_open.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;


    //add to view
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer_open];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer_close];

    //name title for menu and add to the drawer view
    UILabel *menuTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(60.0f, 5.0f, 200.0f, 50.0f)];
    menuTitle.text = @"Menu Options";
    [menuDrawer addSubview:menuTitle];

    //scrollview to contain the buttons of the actions if more drawer items then what is on screen
    UIScrollView *m_scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3.0f, 65.0f, menuDrawerWidth, menuDrawer.frame.size.height)];

    //set options for scrollview design
    [m_scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [m_scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
    [m_scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:YES];
    [m_scrollView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [m_scrollView setIndicatorStyle:UIScrollViewIndicatorStyleDefault];
    [m_scrollView setCanCancelContentTouches:NO];
    [m_scrollView setClipsToBounds:YES];


    //buttons measurement for each menu item
    float originOfButtons = 10.0f;
    float buttonWidth = 227.0f;
    float buttonHeight = 50.0f;
    int buttonSeparator = 10;

    menuItems = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Home", @"Explore", @"Share", @"Profile", @"Settings", nil];
    for(int b=0; b <[menuItems count];b++) {
        UIButton *mybutton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3.0f, originOfButtons, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
        mybutton.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        [mybutton setTag:b];
        [mybutton setTitle:[menuItems objectAtIndex:b] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mybutton setSelected:false];
        [mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(menuSelect:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


        //add button to scrollview
        [m_scrollView addSubview:mybutton];


        //add extra button height and separator for each one
        originOfButtons +=(buttonHeight + buttonSeparator);


    }


    //bounds of scrollview and add it to content size
    [m_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([m_scrollView bounds].size.width, originOfButtons + 85)];

    [menuDrawer addSubview:m_scrollView];
    [self.view addSubview:menuDrawer];




}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Get the stored data before the view loads
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


    //if values exist then already logged in else take to login screen
    if([[[defaults dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"userId"]){

        NSLog(@"userId found");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"userId NOT found");
        StarterViewController *hc=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Starter"];
        [self presentViewController:hc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

-(void)createMenuButton {
    [self drawerAnimation];


}


- (void)menuSelect:(id)sender {
    NSString *selectedTitle = [menuItems objectAtIndex:[sender tag]];

    UIButton *button = (UIButton*) sender;
    mainTitle.text = selectedTitle;
    switch (button.tag) {

        case 0: {
            NSLog(@"settings clicked");
            if(![self.visibleViewController isKindOfClass:[SettingsViewController class]]) {
                SlidingMenuViewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuSettings"];
                [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            }
            break;
        }


        default:
            break;
    }

    [self drawerAnimation];
}


-(void)handleSwipes:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    //calls the animation
    [self drawerAnimation];

}


-(void)drawerAnimation {
    NSLog(@"drawer animation called");
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:-5];

    CGFloat new_x = 0;
    if (menuDrawer.frame.origin.x < self.view.frame.origin.x ) {
        NSLog(@"drawer animation called menu origin if");
        new_x = menuDrawer.frame.origin.x + menuDrawerWidth;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"drawer animation called menu origin else");
        new_x = menuDrawer.frame.origin.x - menuDrawerWidth;
    }
    menuDrawer.frame = CGRectMake(new_x, menuDrawer.frame.origin.y, menuDrawer.frame.size.width, menuDrawer.frame.size.height);

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

@end
```

**ERROR UPDATE**

New Code: (drawerSlide being a BOOL added on top of the .h, and synthesize in .m file of the sliding menu controller)

if (!self.drawerSlide) {
    NSLog(@"drawer animation called menu origin if");
    new_x = menuDrawer.frame.origin.x + menuDrawerWidth;
    self.drawerSlide = YES;
} else {
    NSLog(@"drawer animation called menu origin else");
    new_x = menuDrawer.frame.origin.x - menuDrawerWidth;
    self.drawerSlide = NO;
}

```
2014-05-17 22:31:25.882 Stand[8099:60b] -[ExploreTableViewController drawerAnimation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa47e4e0
2014-05-17 22:31:25.886 Stand[8099:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ExploreTableViewController drawerAnimation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa47e4e0'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01e311e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bb08e5 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01ece243 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x01e2150b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x01e210ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bc2880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    6   UIKit                               0x008723b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    7   UIKit                               0x00b5f8df -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01bc2880 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    9   UIKit                               0x008723b9 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    10  UIKit                               0x00872345 -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    11  UIKit                               0x00973bd1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    12  UIKit                               0x00973fc6 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    13  UIKit                               0x00973243 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    14  UIKit                               0x008b1ddd -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    15  UIKit                               0x008b29d1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1117
    16  UIKit                               0x008845f2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    17  UIKit                               0x0086e353 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x01dba77f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x01dba10b __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01dd71ae __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01dd69d3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01dd67eb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x03bf05ee GSEventRunModal + 192
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x03bf042b GSEventRun + 104
    25  UIKit                               0x00870f9b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    26  Stand                               0x00017d0d main + 141
    27  libdyld.dylib                       0x0257d701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do ? What kind of drawer do you want to make ? could you please elaborate such that I can help you.

Comment: `incompatible pointer to integer conversion UIBarButtonItemStyle` - well you need to fix that first! It's very serious. Passing `self` in your `initWithImage:...` call makes no sense whatever. Never allow warnings to stand; they are important. Remember, _the compiler knows more than you do._

Comment: How can animation duration be a negative number????

Comment: Why are you using `beginAnimations:` / `commitAnimations`? This was discouraged long ago.

Comment: I actually followed a tutorial when making this... What should I be passing other than self?

Comment: Here's another problem: you are saying `@selector(drawerAnimations)` but your method is called `drawerAnimation` so they don't match.

Comment: Do not follow other people's code slavishly. Learn what your code means. Look up methods in the documentation to learn to use them.

Comment: if you look at the error it is calling drawerAnimation I do not know where you got the "s" from...

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem (which could have been stated far more succinctly) is that the `else` branch is never chosen here:

```
if (menuDrawer.frame.origin.x < self.view.frame.origin.x ) {
    NSLog(@"drawer animation called menu origin if");
    new_x = menuDrawer.frame.origin.x + menuDrawerWidth;
} else {
    NSLog(@"drawer animation called menu origin else");
    new_x = menuDrawer.frame.origin.x - menuDrawerWidth;
}
```

Thus, it must be the case that `menuDrawer.frame.origin.x < self.view.frame.origin.x` is always true. Thus, if that isn't what you are expecting, you are testing the wrong thing.

You need to use more logging (or breakpoints and inspection of the variables in the debugger) to see what these values actually are. Then you need to think about why they are not what you expect.

One possibility is that you probably should not be comparing `menuDrawer.frame` to `self.view.frame`. If (as I assume) `menuDrawer` is a subview of `self.view`, then the comparison should be with `self.view.bounds`, not `self.view.frame`. However, it's impossible to be sure without further information.

A further issue (this is probably the actual cause) is that you are comparing the left edges of `menuDrawer` and `self.view`. Nothing in your code guarantees that when the slide-in animation has happened, the left edge of `menuDrawer` will come *further to the right* than the left edge of `self.view`. If even just a tiny bit of `menuDrawer` is still offscreen to the left, the `else` will never be true. If so, you need to think of a better comparison test! What you might do is compare, not to `self.view` at all, but simply to some known integer value (presumably a small negative number) where the value of `menuDrawer.frame.origin.x` *does* change which side of this value it's on. What *I* would do, however, is just throw a BOOL instance variable every time we slide in or out, so that the BOOL keeps track of whether we are in or out and then we can come in if we are out and out if we are in, like this:

```
if (!self.in) {
    NSLog(@"drawer animation called menu origin if");
    new_x = menuDrawer.frame.origin.x + menuDrawerWidth;
    self.in = YES;
} else {
    NSLog(@"drawer animation called menu origin else");
    new_x = menuDrawer.frame.origin.x - menuDrawerWidth;
    self.in = NO;
}
```

Comment: Ok, let me include more code, and the else gets called only when the button is clicked, and the if is actually never called, but look above I added more code

Comment: Sorry, I misread that. But my answer is still the same, if you make allowances. :)

Comment: Yeah thanks, I like your idea, but does it make sense that even with the boolean now the if and the else get called but switch off but for some reason the button still does not slide it out? Do I have to add something to this? And I get this error if I switch tabs and click on the button, posted above.